# Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target in typeScript using with Angular 2

Tags: angular2-template

Object structure look like as below:

```
export class Recipe {
    public name: string;
    public description: string;
    public imagePath: string;

    constructorn(name: string, desc: string, imagePath: string) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = desc;
        this.imagePath = imagePath;
    }
}
```

And my call statement:

```
export class RecipeListComponent implements OnInit {
    recipes: Recipe[] = [
        new Recipe('Test Recipe', 'This is simply a test', 
            'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/06/15/19/09/food-
             1459693_960_720.jpg')
    ];

}
```

Though I am passing all the parameter but still I am getting the error "Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target"

Comment: Check your spellings.

Answer (score 2):

You misspelled `constructor` and might want to use parameter properties.

```
export class Recipe {
    constructor(public name: string, public desc: string, public imagePath: string) {
        // Insert logic..
    }
}
```

This should do the job.